# How to convert each row in hive table to named struct dynamically

Tags: hive, hiveql

Assume that I have a hive table like this:

```
id,name,age
-------------
1,John,25
2,Sarah,30
```

I want to convert each row to a table with single struct column like this:

```
obj
-----
{id:1,name:"John",age:25}
{id:2,name:"Sarah",age:30}
```

But I don't want to define all column's name manually like this:

```
select named_struct("id", id, "name", name, "age", age) as obj from my_table
```

How can I do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try it using Nifi. Converting CSV to JSON. 
The way I see your query is you have a table and you need it in a simple JSON format. 
Should not be difficult via Nifi.